# how to edit the map (.pbm) built by gmapping pkg

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I need to edit the map that built by gmapping pkg. Is there any software that supports this format? almost all software open this format but they don't save changes under this format? Do you have any suggestion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295879/how-to-edit-the-map-(.pbm)-built-by-gmapping-pkg/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2018-06-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2018-07-02**:
GIMP can export PGM files. I assume you meant PGM and not PBM.

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2018-07-02**:
Thanks. I export it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an FAQ for years. You can find many existing threads in e.g. [Google search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aanswers.ros.org+%28.pbm+OR+map%29+edit&oq=site%3Aanswers.ros.org+%28.pbm+OR+map%29+edit).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a bitmap file, so open it in Gimp or a similar paint program.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-07-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2